# Django with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django

I would like to get an advice if what I am doing is right or not.
I have a website where in the home page you search for items in the database, and when find your item, you press the name an you'll be taken to its details page.
I know that Django gives the ability to send the selected item ID in the url and then I can render the details page and send the object in the context. But I want to receive the object as JSON in angularJS in the details page, so I am reading the url in the angular controller and then extracting the id and sending it to the views as an http request to get the item.

I'll put an example code here:

### models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    feature_1 = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    feature_2 = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    feature_3 = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

    def to_json(self):
        json_data = {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'feature_1': self.feature_1,
            'feature_2': self.feature_2,
            'feature_3': self.feature_3,
        }
        return json_data
```

### views:

```
def home_page(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html', {},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def item_details_page(request):
            return render_to_response('item_details.html', {},
                                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def get_item_details(request):
    item_id = int(json.loads(request.body)['item_id'])
    selected_item = Item.objects.get(pk=item_id).to_json()

    return JsonResponse({'item': selected_line}, content_type="application/json", safe=False)
```

### Angular controller

```
ngApp.controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

    $scope.item = null;

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url_get_item,
        data: {
            item_id: parseInt(window.location.href.toString().split('item_details/')[1])
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.item = response.data.item;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });


}]);
```

Is this a good way? 
Is not using Django abilities a bad idea?
Is there a better way to deal with django's returned items in angularJS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way of `Django + Angular` is using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It can much easier return JSON objects, is designed specially for that cases. But your way is also acceptable, specially if there are any other pages, which are not served by `Angular`.